# Invoke one form from another in Visual C++

Tags: c++, forms, invoke

it seems simple question but so far I haven't found the answer. I have 2 forms in my Visual C++ project, and want invoke one from another on button click. How do i do this?

Comment: Well, I just novice and even this simple question could take my 30 mins to find solution. If you also novice and wonder how to do this, here it is:

1) include "Form2.h" in Form1.h

2)in Form1.h on button click:
       Form2 ^r = gcnew Form2();
       r->Show(this);

Comment: If you find the solution yourself, it is quite ok to write it as an **answer** and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just novice and even this simple question could take my 30 mins to find solution. If you also novice and wonder how to do this, here it is:

1. include "Form2.h" in Form1.h
2. in Form1.h on click:

   ```
   Form2 ^r = gcnew Form2();
   r->Show(this);
   ```